# How to replace empty space with character PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace, explode

I have this strange issue with my string $content `1stText 2ndText 3rdText 4thText, 5thText, 6thText`, that I cannot replace empty space with character. The main purpose is that I have to put my string in array, each element will have it's own name afterwards. However, as I am parsing data from another website, get stuck on this:

```
if ($child->nodeName == "div"){
    $textContentArray = preg_split('/\n/', $child->textContent);
    $counter = 0;
    $counter2 = 0;
    foreach ($textContentArray as &$value) 
    {
        if (trim($value) != "")
        {
            $counter2++;
            $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ';', $content);
            $test = explode(';', $string);
            var_dump($string);
```

echo $string gives me 
`1stText2ndText3Text4Text;5Text;6Text`
while var_dump: `string(2) "1stText" string(18) "2ndText" string(3) "3Text" string(16) "4Text"`

4Text(4thText, 5thText, 6thText) consists of three words, so between them, character ";" is added, but between text nodes - not.

I have tried many variations that I found here, simple str_replace doesn't work here somehow. As I am copying string from the table, maybe that would be the issue? But still, why I cannot save it in array separately?

Comment: Has it got any hidden characters there that aren't whitespace... i.e. `&nbsp;`?

Comment: You need to provide us with a way of reproducing your problem. Please [edit] your question to do so. I would recommend having a look at your string using `var_dump` to make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: You need to show us EXACTLY what you are working with. The example value for $content will not produce the example output that you show using the example code. Therefore, it is not possible to identify the problem.

Comment: Your code is working, with test string you've provided, please send some real-life content of $content....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to remove **extra spaces** from string with **single space**. then try to replace that single space with `;` character, finally explode as you wish to get that final array.

```
$str = preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $content ); 

#replaced multiple space with single space
$str = "1stText 2ndText 3rdText 4thText, 5thText, 6thText,"; 
$re = "/\\s+/m"; 
$subst = ";"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
$final=explode(';',$result);

echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($final) ;
echo '</pre>';
```

**EDIT:** `print_r(array_map('trim',explode(";",$result)));`

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but $explode function giving me not what i want to. Right now when I echo my $result I have = ";1stText;;2ndText;;3rdText;;4thText;". After explode() my final result happens to have same issue, as $result[0] is empty, but $result[1] gives full string back. Maybe you might know where is the issue?

Comment: @saulenzo7, $result= ";1stText;;2ndText;;3rdText;;4thText;"; means you have a leading & trailing space along with double space between words..see my edited answer.it may fulfill your requirement. best of luck

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, all data was laying under one of array nodes, so I had to export them separately again. However, it works now. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: @saulenzo7,best of luck..by the way you can accept the answer.